# How much of the International Space Station annual operating costs are due to human crew?

Tags: iss, cost, crewed-spaceflight

The 2013 NASA's Office of Inspector General (OIG) report, [*Extending the Operational Life of 
the International Space Station 
Until 2024*](http://oig.nasa.gov/audits/reports/FY14/IG-14-031.pdf), shows the ISS annual operating costs at $2.9 billion. How much of this cost can be linked to the fact that the ISS has a human crew? It takes a lot to support a human crew in space: more mass to launch in resupply, launches to ferry crew back and forth, life support systems, higher risk monitoring, etc. If it is possible to separate these costs out, I would be very interested in the results.

**Edit:** Some users have mentioned that estimating this depends on what you count and what you don't. Let's imagine that Robonaut were completely capable of performing solo operations on the ISS, and that Robonaut has now been given full responsibility for performing all on-board activities on the ISS. How would this change the annual operating cost? (Don't try to estimate what it would take to maintain Robonaut at this level of activity--assume current Robonaut costs whether those are lower or higher than they would be in this imaginary scenario.)

*Please try not to get hung up on the plausibility of this scenario. I'm not asking for a fully automated ISS--I'm using it as the premise to demonstrate how I want the costs separated.*

Comment: You might find [this recent NASA's Office of Inspector General (OIG) report](http://oig.nasa.gov/audits/reports/FY14/IG-14-031.pdf) (PDF) relevant to your question. It's not an exact science, depends what you count and what you don't, while everything is kinda dependent on one another.

Comment: @TildalWave The first thing I notice is that the annual operating costs are now about $3 billion.

Comment: Yup OIG spanked NASA's bottom a bit there for presenting too low costs, that they were always quoting low estimates instead of actual costs. This issue was also raised a few times by Senate's Appropriations Committee and U.S. Government Accountability Office. Bolden was also asked about similar during one of the CSST hearings that he was summoned to, IIRC sometime this spring (quote: _"Won't you need more money? Because we could give you more if you asked for it."_). It's a mess ... good luck with your question, because I'd like to read good answers to it too. :)

Comment: What are you asking? The difference between the current cost and what it would cost to run the station in its current configuration but without crew? Or what it would cost to run the current experiments in a new minimal-sized station? If you remove the crew, you can also remove the toilet and its recycling system, you can remove most of the air filtration, etc.

Comment: This question is a bit pointless, because a large fraction of the experiments done on the ISS are about the effects of weightlessness on the human body. No bodies = far fewer experiments.

Comment: @Hobbes The cost to run the station in its current configuration but without crew--however, you can consider things like atmosphere doesn't need to be actively maintained.

Comment: @Hobbes I realize that, but I'm not really going to touch the issue of why we would want to run the station unmanned.

Comment: Note that \$2.9B is just NASA's share of ISS operating cost.

Comment: I would say "all of it" because ISS was designed solely to be a human inhabited station.  It has no purpose otherwise and wouldn't have existed unless it had been designed for crew.  I kind of fail to grasp the purpose of this question.  Without crew, the ISS has no raison d'etre.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29634/discussion-between-called2voyage-and-organic-marble).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an approximate answer for the Budget year of 2005.

In 2005 1.8 Billion was spent on the ISS.

**$140 Million** was classified as Cargo/Crew

**$350 Million** was classified as Operation Program Integrity

**$25 Million** was classified as Medical support

**$425 Million** was classified as Launch and Operations (Does Not include Shuttle Launch Costs)

**$70 Million** was classified as Development

**$650 Million** was classified as Craft Operations

**$150 Million** was classified as Flight and Crew Systems.

Now we can safely say that with no crew on-board that the following categories can be excluded: Cargo/Crew, Medical Support and Flight and Crew Systems.

The total cost of those categories adds up to 315 Million.

Now you are left with two categories that may or may not overlap with crew related activities. 
Launch and Operations, and Operation Program Integrity.
Which together compose of $775 Million of the total budget.

Now you can add together the definite and probable cost sectors for the Human Aspect of the ISS which will land you somewhere between 315 Million and 1 Billion (17.5%-55%).

**End Result : Depending on how you look at it, the Human aspect of the 2005 Budget for the ISS will be within the range of 315 Million and 1 Billion (17.5%-55% of the total budget).**

Comment: Thanks for asking the question! Sorry, I wished I could be more specific.